# Aptana - how do I change default from sqlite3 to use MySql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, aptana

Have just installed Aptana and used MacPorts to update all the extras for a Rails project. When 'running' the project to see it in a browser it shows the following error.

Home$ script/rails server
Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources liste
d in your Gemfile.
Try running `bundle install`.

I want it to use MySQL as the default - how do I do this?

Comment: did you check config/database.yml? (adapter name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ages trying to sort this problem out I found a work around. Simply upload your App to Heroku for hosting as it runs a db:rake and accepts data from SQLite3 on deployment. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

in your gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

in database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: your_site_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! Is there a permanent fix for these settings in Aptana?

Comment: Great! I don't use aptana, I don't know :) Please mark my answer as good ;)

Comment: mysql> create database r4rmusic;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'r4rmusic'        I spoke too soon maybe?! I can connect to the sql db and can see the existing databases, but I cannot create a new one and get this error! Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: are you sure you have full rights over the database? did you check login & password? by default, there is no password.

Comment: I didn't set up a password or user so it should just connect??

Comment: default is: username: root password:

Comment: I let password deliberately blank

Answer (score 0):

Access denied is one of the most common problems that a lot of users reportedly go through. 
First things first, make sure you have mentioned the same user in the database.yml file as      the one who is accessing it.

Your user does not have the access, so lets give it to him/her by granting all privileges.
Say, for example

```
development:  
adapter: mysql   
encoding: utf8    
reconnect: false  
database: your_site_development  
pool: 5  
username: some_user  
password: password  
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Say, in this case, login to your database as root and :

```
grant all privileges to 'some_user'@'localhost' on 'your_site_development'
identified by 'password'
```

this would set all access on the database to the user 'some_user' and you are then free to use your development environment. 
Couple of warnings though : notice the adapter i have used is :mysql
and it is recommended that you continue with the default name of the database created i.e. _development for the development environment since there are two other environments.

Also do check the syntax for grant all privileges for single inverted commas and double inverted commas.

Hope this helps.
You can also refer [this](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-grant-revoke-privileges-roles.htm)